# How can we achieve Standard Normal CDF in Oracle SQL or PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

How can i achieve below functionality using Oracle SQL or PL/SQL?

[image: Refer]

Comment: Post words, not pictures.

Comment: Formula is complex can't type it here, so pasted the picture

Comment: Laziness has its place in computer programming.  This is not that place.

Comment: So what is "the standard normal CDF" and "the standard normal PDF". I mean, I can read the formulae, but I don't have a clue what CDF and PDF is in this case. Thanks!

Comment: @BobJarvis you're doing better than me then; I can't see the picture because of a firewall. (Vivek - that's part of the reason why we ask for text not images.)

Comment: @Boneist: I just pulled the terms from the question title. :-) I *do* wish that SO had the LaTex capabilities in its markdown that MathOverflow does. If the following is formatted properly it does, but it's not advertised: $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!\quad\forall n\in\mathbb N$  Drat - it doesn't. :-(

Comment: Oracle SQL and PL/SQL don't have a built-in function for the standard normal CDF. The first question I would ask you is, what do you need it for - and especially, why in Oracle? There are plenty of implementations in procedural and object-oriented languages. If you are performing statistical analysis it is more likely that you should use the t-distribution instead (Oracle **does** have built-in t-tests for that). If you absolutely need the standard normal CDF, load a look-up table (you can find values online so you just copy and paste) and write simple linear interpolation between the nodes.

Answer (score 5):

This stored procedure gives the same result as NORMDIST function in Calc.
The parameters that need to be passed are x, mean, standard deviation and cumulative.
Cumulative parameter gives a choice to get normal distribution value at x (0) or cumulative probability of value<=x (1).

```
create or replace FUNCTION NORMDIST(x_value number,mean_value number,stddev_value number, cumulative NUMBER DEFAULT 0)
RETURN NUMBER IS

        x number;
        t number;
        z number;
        ans number;

BEGIN
  IF (stddev_value = 0) THEN
  RETURN 1;
  END IF;

  x := (x_value-mean_value)/stddev_value;

  IF cumulative = 1 THEN
    z := abs(x)/SQRT(2);
    t := 1/(1+0.5*z);
    ans := t*exp(-z*z-1.26551223+t*(1.00002368+t*(0.37409196+t*(0.09678418+t*(-0.18628806+t*(0.27886807+t*(-1.13520398+t*(1.48851587+t*(-0.82215223+t*0.17087277)))))))))/2;
    If (x <= 0)
     Then RETURN ans;
     Else return  1-ans;
    End if;
  ELSE

   RETURN 1/(sqrt(2*3.14159265358979)*stddev_value)*Exp(-(Power(x_value-mean_value,2)/(2*Power(stddev_value,2)) ));
  END IF;

END;
/
```

Comment: This does work indeed, but I am wondering how did those constants were calculated.

Answer (score 1):

```
--I wrote this function in PL/SQL and it works. I compared results with the NORMDIST 
 --Function in excel and the results match very closely. You will need to pass the  
  --following --parameters to the function.

-- 1. Value of X
-- 2. Value of Mean
-- 3. Value of Standard Deviation

--This function returns the same result  when you pass cumulative=TRUE in excel.


create or replace FUNCTION NORMSDIST(x_value number,mean_value number,stddev_value number)
RETURN NUMBER IS

        x number;
        t number;
        z number;
        ans number;

BEGIN
  IF (stddev_value = 0) THEN
  RETURN 1;
  END IF;

  x := (x_value-mean_value)/stddev_value;

  z := abs(x)/SQRT(2);

  t := 1.0/(1.0+0.5*z);

  ans := t*exp(-z*z-1.26551223+t*(1.00002368+t*(0.37409196+t*(0.09678418+t*(-0.18628806+t*(0.27886807+t*(-1.13520398+t*(1.48851587+t*(-0.82215223+t*0.17087277)))))))))/2.0;

     If (x <= 0)   
     Then RETURN ans;
     Else return  1-ans;
    End if; 

END NORMSDIST;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick solution, I have not tried to gain maximum precision or performance. Depending on your req, you might need to tweak number format, precision, calculation logic, etc.

```
create or replace function calc_sn_pdf(x in number) return number
is
 pi      CONSTANT NUMBER := 3.14159265358979;
begin
  return 1/sqrt(2*pi) * exp(-x*x/2);
end;
/
```

The cdf must be approximated (as it is az integral function which has no simple mathematical formula), one possible approximation is implemented as follows. Many other approximations can be found on Wikipedia.

```
create or replace function calc_sn_cdf(x in number) return number
is
 b0 CONSTANT NUMBER :=  0.2316419; 
 b1 CONSTANT NUMBER :=  0.319381530;
 b2 CONSTANT NUMBER := -0.356563782; 
 b3 CONSTANT NUMBER :=  1.781477937; 
 b4 CONSTANT NUMBER := -1.821255978; 
 b5 CONSTANT number :=  1.330274429;
 v_t  number;
begin
  --see 26.2.17 at http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_932.htm
  --see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Numerical_approximations_for_the_normal_CDF
  --Zelen & Severo (1964) approximation
  if x < 0 then
    --this approximation works for x>0, but cdf is symmetric for x=0:
    return 1 - calc_sn_cdf(-x);
  else
    v_t := 1 / (1 + b0*x);
    return 1 - calc_sn_pdf(x)*(b1*v_t + b2*v_t*v_t + b3*v_t*v_t*v_t + b4*v_t*v_t*v_t*v_t + b5*v_t*v_t*v_t*v_t*v_t);
  end if;    
end;
/
```

Btw, if you need to run these functions a lot of time, it would be useful to turn on native pl/sql compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me to get z value (equivalent to standardize in Excel) for grading/regrading the students marks and get new marks based on new mean and standard deviation.

```
create or replace FUNCTION STANDARDIZE(x_value number,mean_value number,stddev_value number)
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
   IF (stddev_value = 0) THEN
  RETURN 1;
   END IF;
 RETURN  (x_value-mean_value)/stddev_value;
END STANDARDIZE;
```

Once you get the zvalue (standardize) then next step is to decide the new standard deviation and new mean deviation.
Formula to compute the new values will be as below

```
create or replace FUNCTION f_get_new_marks(zvalue  number,p_new_mean number,p_new_std_dev number) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  IF   ROUND(((zvalue * p_new_std_dev) + p_new_mean),0) >100 then 
    return 100;
    else 
return ROUND(( (zvalue * p_new_std_dev) + p_new_mean),0);
end if;    
END f_get_new_marks;
```